# Django factory boy mock model method in factory

Tags: django, factory-boy

My model's save method is calling an api after saving. To test my application I am using `DjangoModelFactory` to generate objects for testing. However, the api still being called.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.call_api()
```

I have tried mocking the method but it is not working

```
#...
from .models import MyModel

@pytest.mark.django_db
@patch("MyModel.call_api")
class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory, factory.base.BaseFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

My Question is, how can I use mock methods when I use it with factories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper extension point is [`Factory._create`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.Factory._create):

```py
class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        with patch("MyModel.call_api"):
            return super()._create(model_class, *args, **kwargs)
```

Just a quick note: you don't need to inherit from `factory.base.Factory` in addition to `factory.django.DjangoModelFactory`, the latter is already a subclass of the former.